# "yf_convert_to_wide" command from "yfR" package not working in R

Tags: r, yahoo-finance

I was trying to download some data from Yahoo Finance and I used the "yfR" package with the following commands:

```
library(yfR)

first.date <- Sys.Date()-365
last.date <- Sys.Date()
freq.data <- "daily"
tickers <- c("SPY", "EFA", "IJS", "EEM", "AGG", "FTSEMIB.MI")

l.out  <-  yf_get(tickers = tickers, 
                  first_date = first.date,
                  last_date = last.date)

l.wide  <- yf_convert_to_wide(l.out)
```

The last command unfortunately is not working and I really don't know why.
This is the error I get:

```
Error in `instrument_base_errors()`:
! 'all_of' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyr'
Caused by error:
! 'all_of' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyr'
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Can someone help me? I don't want to use the package "BatchGetSymbols" because I know it will be deactivated, so if someone has some hints I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @akrun and OP, I wonder if you're both using same version of tidyr? Maybe `all_of()` is re-exported in one version but not another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: update tidyr.

Slightly longer answer: The root of the issue is that the package [source](https://github.com/ropensci/yfR/blob/main/R/yf_data_convert_to_wide.R) calls `tidyr::all_of()`. This really should probably be `tidyselect::all_of()`, and I've filed a [bug report](https://github.com/ropensci/yfR/issues/22) to that effect. But `all_of()` is re-exported by tidyr as of v1.2.0 ([changelog](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#general-1-2-0)), so the function should work as long as your tidyr version is up to date.

Comment: Solved by updating tidyr. Thanks a lot!